# How to summarize the duplicate strings

Tags: awk

My input file: ( duplicated UUID (ex: `WW000001`) listed in both HBA0 and HBA1 and both of it has a unique name , ex: `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sde` )

```
/dev/sda HBA0 WW000001
/dev/sdb HBA0 WW000002
/dev/sdc HBA0 WW000003
/dev/sdd HBA0 WW000004
/dev/sde HBA1 WW000001
/dev/sdf HBA1 WW000002
/dev/sdg HBA1 WW000003
/dev/sdh HBA1 WW000004
```

The same UUID (ex: `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sde` ) means actually the same disk but have a different disk name and HBA path.

I want to get a balanced list ( unique UUID listed balanced in `HBA0` and `HBA1` ). The sequence is don't care, as long as UUID is unique in final result and the `HBA0` and `HBA1` have the same disk numbers.

ex:

```
/dev/sda HBA0 WW000001
/dev/sdb HBA0 WW000002
/dev/sdg HBA1 WW000003
/dev/sdh HBA1 WW000004
```

finally, I will get the balanced list:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdg
/dev/dfh
```

Comment: Could you please explain more about logic that how disks `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sde` are same?

Comment: In MPIO, they are the same when UUID is the same.

Comment: So it means either `/dev/sdc` gets printed or `/dev/sdg` gets printed doesn't matter for you?(No I believe), sorry just trying to understand logic by which you want to print the lines.

Comment: yes, it is matter since their HBA is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk '{
    dev[$2,$3] = $1                     # make device list indexed by HBA and UUID
    uuid[$3]++                          # make UUID list
}
END {
    j = 0                               # reset HBA number
    for (i in uuid) {                   # loop over UUID list
        hba = "HBA" j                   # "HBA0" or "HBA1"
        print dev[hba,i], hba, i        # print the list
        j = xor(j, 1)                   # flip between "0" and "1"
    }
}' inputfile
```

Result:

```
/dev/sda HBA0 WW000001
/dev/sdf HBA1 WW000002
/dev/sdc HBA0 WW000003
/dev/sdh HBA1 WW000004
```

In order to achieve the `balanced` list, it alters the `HBA` between `HBA0` and `HBA1` one by one.
The device sequence differs from the posted example, but I hope it will meet your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can either sort your file if not sorted, and then use a combination of `head`, `tail`, and `wc` to pick off a balanced (an even number of) rows from the beginning and end of your file, e.g.

```
$ head -n$(($(wc -l < file) / 4)) file; tail -n$(($(wc -l < file) / 4)) file
/dev/sda HBA0 WW000001
/dev/sdb HBA0 WW000002
/dev/sdg HBA1 WW000003
/dev/sdh HBA1 WW000004
```

Essentially, since your file has two-halves that you want the first and last quarter of lines from, above `wc` is used to count the total number of lines and then output the first and last quarter. It does required multiple subshells, so if you have a million records, `awk` would be a better choice, but there is always more than one way to *skin-the-cat*...

If you need to sort first, then `sort -k1,8 file` will do and since you have tagged your question `[bash]` you can simply use a *process substitution* for the final `file` in each of the two commands, e.g. `< <(sort -k1,8 file)`.

To get your final list, just pick off the first field with `cut`, e.g.

```
$ cut -d' ' -f1 < <(head -n$(($(wc -l < file) / 4)) file; tail -n$(($(wc -l < file) / 4)) file)
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdg
/dev/sdh
```